# Reset background-image animation using css only

Tags: javascript, css, animation, background, reset

If I replace a background-image onhover with a svg containing an animation, this works as expected - the image shows up on hover and the animation starts.
But, if I hover a second time, the animation does not restart, it shows up in its already finished state. I searched the web and found various solutions but all involved javascript.

Is there (in 2022) any solution to restart the animation on each hover using *only css* and *no javascript*?

```css
#d1 {
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2024%2024%22%20style%3D%22{fill%3Avar%28--col%29}%22%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M16.59%208.59L12%2013.17%207.41%208.59%206%2010l6%206%206-6z%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E);
  background-size: 24px 24px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
}

#d1:hover {
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20id%3D%22a%22%20%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2024%2024%22%20fill%3D%22%23dd0000%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M16.59%208.59L12%2013.17%207.41%208.59%206%2010l6%206%206-6z%22%2F%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CanimateTransform%20attributeName%3D%22transform%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20attributeType%3D%22XML%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3D%22rotate%22%20begin%3D%220%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20from%3D%220%200%200%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20to%3D%22-180%200%200%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dur%3D%22250ms%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fill%3D%22freeze%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20repeatCount%3D%221%22%20%20restart%3D%22always%22%2F%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fsvg%3E);
}
```

```html
<div id="d1"></div>
```

## EDIT

As a workaround, the background image property can be animated itself, replaced with sliced version of the SVG containing a frame each. Using sass this can be easily done for simple animations. This solution bloats the css with all the svgs and gets complicated for more sophisticad animations, so a solution by just replacing the image would be better

Here an example for a selectbox animated on focus

```css
@keyframes rot {
  0% {background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22 viewBox=%220 0 24 24%22 fill=%22%2306d%22 transform=%22rotate(0)%22%3E%3Cpath d=%22M16.59 8.59L12 13.17 7.41 8.59 6 10l6 6 6-6z%22/%3E%3C/svg%3E");}
  10% {background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22 viewBox=%220 0 24 24%22 fill=%22%2306d%22 transform=%22rotate(-18)%22%3E%3Cpath d=%22M16.59 8.59L12 13.17 7.41 8.59 6 10l6 6 6-6z%22/%3E%3C/svg%3E");}
  20% {background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22 viewBox=%220 0 24 24%22 fill=%22%2306d%22 transform=%22rotate(-36)%22%3E%3Cpath d=%22M16.59 8.59L12 13.17 7.41 8.59 6 10l6 6 6-6z%22/%3E%3C/svg%3E");}
  30% {background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22 viewBox=%220 0 24 24%22 fill=%22%2306d%22 transform=%22rotate(-54)%22%3E%3Cpath d=%22M16.59 8.59L12 13.17 7.41 8.59 6 10l6 6 6-6z%22/%3E%3C/svg%3E");}
  40% {background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22 viewBox=%220 0 24 24%22 fill=%22%2306d%22 transform=%22rotate(-72)%22%3E%3Cpath d=%22M16.59 8.59L12 13.17 7.41 8.59 6 10l6 6 6-6z%22/%3E%3C/svg%3E");}
  50% {background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22 viewBox=%220 0 24 24%22 fill=%22%2306d%22 transform=%22rotate(-90)%22%3E%3Cpath d=%22M16.59 8.59L12 13.17 7.41 8.59 6 10l6 6 6-6z%22/%3E%3C/svg%3E");}
  60% {background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22 viewBox=%220 0 24 24%22 fill=%22%2306d%22 transform=%22rotate(-108)%22%3E%3Cpath d=%22M16.59 8.59L12 13.17 7.41 8.59 6 10l6 6 6-6z%22/%3E%3C/svg%3E");}
  70% {background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22 viewBox=%220 0 24 24%22 fill=%22%2306d%22 transform=%22rotate(-126)%22%3E%3Cpath d=%22M16.59 8.59L12 13.17 7.41 8.59 6 10l6 6 6-6z%22/%3E%3C/svg%3E");}
  80% {background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22 viewBox=%220 0 24 24%22 fill=%22%2306d%22 transform=%22rotate(-144)%22%3E%3Cpath d=%22M16.59 8.59L12 13.17 7.41 8.59 6 10l6 6 6-6z%22/%3E%3C/svg%3E");}
  90% {background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22 viewBox=%220 0 24 24%22 fill=%22%2306d%22 transform=%22rotate(-162)%22%3E%3Cpath d=%22M16.59 8.59L12 13.17 7.41 8.59 6 10l6 6 6-6z%22/%3E%3C/svg%3E");}
  100% {background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22 viewBox=%220 0 24 24%22 fill=%22%2306d%22 transform=%22rotate(-180)%22%3E%3Cpath d=%22M16.59 8.59L12 13.17 7.41 8.59 6 10l6 6 6-6z%22/%3E%3C/svg%3E");}
}

select {
  appearance: none;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22 viewBox=%220 0 24 24%22 fill=%22%23000%22%3E%3Cpath d=%22M16.59 8.59L12 13.17 7.41 8.59 6 10l6 6 6-6z%22/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-size: 24px 24px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right center;
  outline: none;
}

select:focus {
  animation: rot linear 200ms;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Nope. The problem is the browser cache. It caches the SVG image with the "animation state". You can notice how when you click again in "Run code snippet" it also goes without animation even on the first hover. Why don't you try CSS animations instead of SVG animations? They are made exactly for this. It even allows for reverse animations and half-animations easily (try to move the mouse fast over the icon and you'll notice how it runs half animation, stops and returns back to its position):

```css
#d1 {
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2024%2024%22%20style%3D%22{fill%3Avar%28--col%29}%22%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M16.59%208.59L12%2013.17%207.41%208.59%206%2010l6%206%206-6z%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E);
  background-size: 24px 24px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  transition: transform 300ms;
}

#d1:hover {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="d1"></div>
```

Just add a color filter or whatever if you want to change the color.

Comment: Unfortunately this is no option, the animation has to be in the background image not on the container. Even before/after ist not an option and I can not add containers or subelements

Comment: @Joschi Then you are not able to do that. Images are cached by the browser, and that's not under your control. You, at least, need to have a before/after element with the backgound-image: https://www.sitepoint.com/css3-transform-background-image/

Comment: My hope was that this would be possible somehow using events within the SVG to restart the animation

Comment: @Joschi Yeah, I got curious and I've also searched about that, but there are no mouse events over the SVG to restart the animations :-( There's an `<object>` HTML element which can load a SVG and the browser will not cache it, but `<object>` is not suitable for a `background-image` :-/

Comment: The only working but somewhat ugly solution I found yet is slicing the animation in multiple svgs (using sass its easy) and animate the bg-image over those.

Comment: @Joschi oh, that sounds interesting to watch. If you edit the answer with that workaround (if possible), it would be awesome!

Comment: OK I added this to the question.

Comment: @Joschi Hey, that's clever. Cool.